# How to make buttons from background places?

Tags: android

i have this picture.

[image]

i want to make every red square a button and move to a new activity.Is that possible?thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible if you use overlays
[Here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) is a tutorial

Comment: on the map i will use geopoint,as in the example,to mark my place!But in the picture how i will find the placE?

Comment: // Convert geo coordinates to screen pixels
    Point screenPoint = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(geoPoint, screenPoint);   Check this out http://www.androidsnippets.com/drawing-an-image-as-a-map-overlay2

Answer (score 1):

I figure out that the image is inside an ImageView...

You can use the onTouchEvent of the View class to know in what pixel have been touch and calculate on which square the user have tap.

Comment: yes the image is an imageView.How will i find the pixel have been touch?

Comment: you can set the handler with the setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener l) and use the MotionEvent to first know if is a TAP action, and then use the getX and getY methods of MotionEvent to obtain the position.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question, yes its possible.

Comment: do you have any tutorial on that?

Comment: No I don't know of any tutorial to tell you how to detect MotionEvent in an ImageView and watch for clicks in certain rectangles described by pixels.